# Removing AVPlayerItem observers

Tags: iphone, avqueueplayer, avplayeritem

If I use KVO to observe my player items like this:

```
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
    [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:MyClassKVOContext];
    [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:MyClassKVOContext];
    [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:MyClassKVOContext];
    [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"loadedTimeRanges" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:MyClassKVOContext];
```

Two questions:

1) Do I need to remove my observers once the item finishes playing? (i.e. in `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`)

2) If I call `[_avQueuePlayer removeAllItems]` does it also remove each item's observers?

Answer (score 1):

make your player object(AVPlayerItem *playerItem) Globally and set its property and synthesize it.

1) Do I need to remove my observers once the item finishes playing? (i.e. in AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification)

> > Yes, your need to remove all observer when you are about to leave that view controller where that player is playing. Not after finishes playing.

2) If I call [_avQueuePlayer removeAllItems] does it also remove each item's observers?

> > Yes, it remove all observer that are set for that global variable.

Comment: You can also use AVPlayerItem removeObserver:forKeyPath method for removing observer for particular key.

Comment: I have multiple AVPlayerItem globally since it plays across multiple viewcontrollers. If I call removeAllItems on the player, it removes the observers? However by default when an item finishes playing it does not?